# How to await TaskAwaiter or ConfiguredTaskAwaitable in F#

Tags: f#, async-await

In C# awaiting the task awaiter is or ConfiguredTaskAwaitable is quite easy - just use `await`. What is the alternative for F#?

```
let! result = ...? doSomething().ConfigureAwait(false) ...?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# async workflows and C# async-await keywords are two entirely separate mechanisms, and as such they are not directly compatible (though no doubt you can have wrappers that make that possible and most likely there are already wrappers like this around).

If you want to combine tasks with F# async workflow, you'd use the actual tasks rather than awaiters:

```
let! result = Async.AwaitTask task
```

If you have an API that gives you awaiters rather than tasks, here's a heavy-handed attempt at making an async out of a `TaskAwaiter<'T>`:

```
module Async = 
    let fromTaskAwaiter (awaiter: TaskAwaiter<'a>) =
        async {
            use handle = new SemaphoreSlim(0)
            awaiter.OnCompleted(fun () -> ignore (handle.Release()))
            let! _ = handle.AvailableWaitHandle |> Async.AwaitWaitHandle
            return awaiter.GetResult()
        }
```

Comment: how did you reference the C# System.Runtime.CompilerServices dll?  The one packaged in F# shadows the C# one where this struct is defined, and I'm running into this same problem.

Comment: System.Runtime.CompilerServices is a namespace in System.Core, I doubt it comes in as a separate dll. At least not in the framework version I'm looking at. Not sure what's packaged in F#.

Comment: so to answer your question - all I did was `open System.Runtime.CompilerServices`.

Comment: This was entirely my screwup: I was building against .net 4 instead of 4.5, which is where the new classes were introduced :-/